# How can I optimize an update query on a large table with 10 million rows?

Tags: postgresql, performance, sql-update, large-data

Update on large table is taking a lot of time. 10 million rows need to be updated.

Update is taking about 30 min. The select query is taking less than a minute. Main problem is with update query.

```
EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE) update invoice_line il set product_category = (
select tag.name from odoo_v2.product_product pp 
inner join odoo_v2.product_product_tags_rel pp_tag on pp_tag.product_id = pp.id inner join odoo_v2.bboxx_tags tag on tag.id = pp_tag.tag_id where il.invoice_id like 'SAJ%' and pp.id = il.product_id and tag_type = 'Category 2');

Taking forever with EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)
```

I have also tried creating temporary table, created an index on **id** and then used update, but the result is the same.

```
EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE) create temp table category_data                                                                                                                                                          
AS select tag.name, il.id from invoice_line il
inner join odoo_v2.product_product pp on pp.id = il.product_id
inner join odoo_v2.product_product_tags_rel pp_tag on pp_tag.product_id = pp.id
inner join odoo_v2.bboxx_tags tag on tag.id = pp_tag.tag_id
where il.invoice_id like 'SAJ%' and tag_type = 'Category 2';
                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=71.83..933354.85 rows=5367666 width=16) (actual time=4041.650..47132.534 rows=10631312 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (il.product_id = pp.id)
   Buffers: shared hit=139833 read=412425
   I/O Timings: read=8797104.138
   ->  Seq Scan on invoice_line il  (cost=0.00..802931.97 rows=20419716 width=8) (actual time=4016.593..42177.674 rows=11477350 loops=1)
         Filter: ((invoice_id)::text ~~ 'SAJ%'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 518814
         Buffers: shared hit=139812 read=412418
         I/O Timings: read=8789150.707
   ->  Hash  (cost=69.25..69.25 rows=207 width=20) (actual time=21.119..23.879 rows=742 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49kB
         Buffers: shared hit=21 read=7
         I/O Timings: read=7953.430
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=39.37..69.25 rows=207 width=20) (actual time=9.046..23.593 rows=742 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (pp.id = pp_tag.product_id)
               Buffers: shared hit=21 read=7
               I/O Timings: read=7953.430
               ->  Seq Scan on product_product pp  (cost=0.00..24.86 rows=786 width=4) (actual time=0.024..11.483 rows=786 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=11 read=6
                     I/O Timings: read=7952.306
               ->  Hash  (cost=36.78..36.78 rows=207 width=16) (actual time=7.470..9.726 rows=742 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 46kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=10 read=1
                     I/O Timings: read=1.124
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.04..36.78 rows=207 width=16) (actual time=3.499..5.850 rows=742 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (pp_tag.tag_id = tag.id)
                           Buffers: shared hit=10 read=1
                           I/O Timings: read=1.124
                           ->  Seq Scan on product_product_tags_rel pp_tag  (cost=0.00..28.37 rows=1937 width=8) (actual time=0.024..0.623 rows=1937 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=9
                           ->  Hash  (cost=2.94..2.94 rows=8 width=16) (actual time=1.180..1.185 rows=8 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                 Buffers: shared hit=1 read=1
                                 I/O Timings: read=1.124
                                 ->  Seq Scan on bboxx_tags tag  (cost=0.00..2.94 rows=8 width=16) (actual time=0.011..1.173 rows=8 loops=1)
                                       Filter: ((tag_type)::text = 'Category 2'::text)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 67
                                       Buffers: shared hit=1 read=1
                                       I/O Timings: read=1.124
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=56
 Planning Time: 17.905 ms
 Execution Time: 56722.427 ms
(43 rows)

create index idx_category_data on category_data (id);

EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE) update invoice_line set product_category = category_data.name from category_data where invoice_line.id = category_data.id;

It is running forever with EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)
```

The last approach I want to consider is creating temp table, update data, truncate actual table and insert temp data in actual table. Please help is there any way to optimize it.

Comment: My first guess would be that the subquery is unnecessary, as both outer and inner queries are querying the same table, but it is hard to tell without sample data. Please add the create table and insert statements (preferably within a fiddle) and the exact expected results.

Comment: There is no outer join. I am querying data from different schema. Select is taking less than a minute. Its update that is taking time.

Comment: Yes, it is only the update that takes all the time. `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` might show more, particularly if  `track_io_timing = on`. Perhaps you got many indexes or slow triggers on the table.

Comment: @user19846678 oh I see it now, the tables are in different schemata ... in that case try tracking the plan and timing as suggested by Laurenz

Comment: What is the plan for the SELECT version of this query?  (I would expect it to be similar to the top hash join in the update plan, but that took 204s, much longer than you report for the SELECT)

Comment: Your two instances of invoice_line appear to be in the same schema.  If "id" is a primary key, then that self join seems to be unnecessary.  If it is not a primary key, then it unclear what this update is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you are updating huge part of the table(10.6m/13.1m=~%80). Instead of that create a temp table with the columns you need(as well as updated column values) and insert the data from the excluded part (such as `where il.invoice_id not like 'SAJ%' and tag_type != 'Category 2')` ) . At the end you can swap your temp table and the actual tables. Of course, in advance it is better to check triggers and indexes as Laurenz said.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN as mentioned I don't want to follow that approach.

Comment: @jjanes I have updated the query plan for select. Please have a look at it.

Comment: It is not the same approach. Please take a look at it again.

Comment: You should show both plans (update and simple select), not replace one plan with the other.  But now you've edited your UPDATE statement rather fundamentally and without explanation.  Is your old question even relevant to your new UPDATE?